# Swift 5 : how to deallocate memory, allocated by shared library

Tags: swift

I have the following C function inside a shared library :

```
int GetRxDataBlock( char** data )
{
   CHECK_FACADE_INITIALIZATION( "getRxDataBlock : Client facade not initialized", __LINE__ );

   if ( data == nullptr ) {
      printErrorMsg("getRxDataBlock : nullptr", __LINE__);
      return -1;
   }

   int ret = 0;
   try {
      std::string rxData = g_facade.value()->getRxDataBlock();
      *data = (char*) malloc(rxData.size() + 1);
      memset(*data, 0, rxData.size() + 1 );
      memcpy(*data, rxData.c_str(), rxData.size());
   }catch(...) {
      ret = -1;
   }

   return ret;
}
```

And this is the way I call it from Swift code :
var rxData: UnsafeMutablePointer? = nil

```
let apiResponse = GetRxDataBlock(&rxData)
print("Rx data : ret = \(apiResponse)")

if let dataStr = rxData {
    let rxStr = String(cString: dataStr)
    print("Rx data = \(rxStr)")
}
```

What is the correct way to deallocate memory returned by `GetRxDataBlock` function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc()`ed memory must be released with `free()`:

```
if let dataStr = rxData {
    // do something with `dataStr`
    // ...
    free(dataStr)
}
```

This is also a good use-case for `defer`, which calls the closure just before the scope of the block is left:

```
if let dataStr = rxData {
    defer { free(dataStr) }
    // do something with `dataStr`
    // ...
}
```

On Apple platforms, `free()` is imported from the standard C library as part of the `Darwin` module (which is imported by `Foundation`, `AppKit`, or `UIKit`). On Linux you would `import Glibc`.

Comment: Is free() a built-in function?

Comment: @Dmitry: It is imported from the standard C library, see update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment - that's what I was looking for